# How to remove u' (unicode) from a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, unicode

I have a dictionary

```
{u'value1': {u'Capacity1': 0, u'E1': 'None', u'status': u'ONLINE', u'name': u'value1', u'perf': 'None', u'Id': u'2005', u'id1': u'3000', u'Capacity2': 4}}
```

How do I remove the u' from both the key and the value (which itself is another dictionary?))

Thanks!

Comment: `u` denotes its unicode string. y u want to remove it??

Comment: I don't think you can. It indicates that the string is represented as unicode, so it is not a part of the string.

Btw in `python 3.x` there is default unicode support, so the `u` prefix is not used.

Comment: I m comparing it to another data which does not have u' in it.

Answer (score 5):

One possibility might be (assuming Python 2):

```
def encode_dict(d, codec='utf8'):
    ks = d.keys()
    for k in ks:
        val = d.pop(k)
        if isinstance(val, unicode):
            val = val.encode(codec)
        elif isinstance(val, dict):
            val = encode_dict(val, codec)
        if isinstance(k, unicode):
            k = k.encode(codec)
        d[k] = val
    return d

top_d = encode_dict(top_d)
```

You do need to remove (via `.pop`) each Unicode key `k`, then insert it back (with the newly encoded `val`) after encoding `k` into a byte string, otherwise (since, for keys made up only of ASCII characters, it is the case that `k == k.encode('utf-8')`), the Unicode key would remain.  Try that by using `d.get` in lieu of `d.pop` -- it doesn't do what you ask.

Whether you actually **need** what you ask is actually pretty dubious; if all the Unicode strings in `d` (and embedded dicts therein) are made up only of ASCII characters, then `d == encode_dict(d)`.  However, the "stringified" forms would indeed look cosmetically different, and I guess that might be what you're after.

Answer (score 4):

`u` denotes the `unicode` representation.

you dont need to remove it or do something, just go for your code and do comparison

demo:

```
>>> type(u'b')
<type 'unicode'>

>>> u'b' == 'b'
True
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue as I needed each dict item to be used in an SQL expression and the u' was getting in the way.

This is what worked for me:

```
    for x,y in mylist.items():
        mylist[x] = str(y)
```

Very simple :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to compare,as others suggested you need not change it but if you need it.Here is it.

```
In [90]: d
Out[90]: 
{u'value1': {u'Capacity1': 0,
  u'Capacity2': 4,
  u'E1': 'None',
  u'Id': u'2005',
  u'id1': u'3000',
  u'name': u'value1',
  u'perf': 'None',
  u'status': u'ONLINE'}}

In [91]: c_k,c_v=d.keys(),d.values()

In [92]: z=[{str(k):str(v) for (k,v) in c_v[0].items()}]

In [93]: z1=[str(i) for i in c_k]

In [94]: dict(zip(z1,z))
Out[94]: 
{'value1': {'Capacity1': '0',
  'Capacity2': '4',
  'E1': 'None',
  'Id': '2005',
  'id1': '3000',
  'name': 'value1',
  'perf': 'None',
  'status': 'ONLINE'}}
```